# porting c++ opengl game to android and IOS in the easiest way

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, game-engine, porting

I have simple c++ game with opengl and I would like to port it into android platform and ios. I have read many articles but i can not find any tool that can do this at the same time.

Can i use cocos2d-x?
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/download

Or what is the best way to port c++ game to android and ios.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at SDL 2.0. It supports OpenGL, iOS and Android out of the box and is a great way to hide platform differences. If you already have a OpenGL game it should be very easy.

There is a great talk about the topic from Steam Dev Days:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeMPCSqQ-34&list=PLckFgM6dUP2hc4iy-IdKFtqR9TeZWMPjm

Besides SDL 2.0 is free to use ( zlib licensed ).

The SDL library is available from here:

http://www.libsdl.org

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I understand you correctly I can import c++ openGl game to SDL or need to be rebuilded again?

Comment: Well you need to update your C++ code to use SDL instead of whatever gui-framework that you currently use (such as Glut or FreeGlut). Afterwards you need to compile and link with SDL. (For more info about compiling for specific platforms I suggest that you take a look at the tutorials: https://wiki.libsdl.org/Tutorials )

Answer (score 0):

In android case , find NDK , native activity, difference with openGL ES to OpenGL.
I think it is not hard to find. Sample is in NDK source pack.